# How to store user specific data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql, mern

I am trying to create an app using the MERN stack in which, every user apart from login credentials will have different posts that he has created and every post will have its own property like title, description, creator, creationTime, etc. I am unable to figure out how to store the user-specific data in MongoDB.
Should I make different collections for different users or should I embed the post inside a single collection.

Comment: In general similar information should be stored in one collection. Although it is possible in MongoDB to join several collections (using `$lookup`) NoSQL databases are not optimized for joins like relational RDBMS are.

Comment: I am new to MongoDB. So, which method will be more efficient considering memory as well as fetch time

Comment: What's not clear with my comment when I write "MongoDB is not optimized for join/lookup"? Be sure that you don't mistake "collection" and "document", see [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/)